# Vue devtools in Electron not displaying components

Tags: vue.js, electron

I've tried a few methods of installing vue dev tools for my Electron app, but I can't get the dev tools to actually show any of my components. It's just showing an empty window, stating to select a component to view from the list, which is empty.

Currently, the method I have the vue dev tools installed is with this 
**NPM:** electron-devtools-installer

**My App:** https://github.com/Ampix0/tickr-for-robinhood

**Electron-Vue boilerplate:** https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue

As far as I see online it looks like maybe some people have had some success? But I see mostly this is a huge struggle it seems. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Electron-Vue already includes Vue Dev Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean like this image:

[image]

in your code `app/src/main/index.js` remove the condition at line 15

or set it to equals

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { // change !== to ===
    require('vue-devtools').uninstall()
}
```

Comment: I'll double check this soon but it looks like you have it working there! Thank you!